# Why does 11.04 server fail to boot with 'can't find /sbin/init'?

Tags: server, boot, reboot

I just restarted my server and now when I boot up one of my Ubuntu 11.04 Server instances I am greeted with errors. It doesn't boot up. [image: Screenshot of boot up screen]

I am pretty sure this is not a hardware error as I have other servers that are successfully booting up. In case it is relevant, all of these machines are running on a Proxmox server.

I tried running the recovery tool but I am not having any luck solving anything. When I try to mount /dev/sda1 in recovery it looks like there is nothing but the kernel on the disk. What can I try?? Needless to say I really don't want to reinstall Ubuntu and wipe my disk clean.

Thanks!

Edit: When I try to mount the root partition and go in the `target` folder I only get:
[image: Target]

It looks like I am supposed to mount the /dev/WEBAPPS-LOCAL/root drive to the /target folder, but when I do I get a "Segmentation fault" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first of all this appears to be a KVM running on Proxmox, right?

`/dev/sda1` appears to be a separate boot partition (`/boot`). You are probably looking to set `/dev/sda2` as the target in recovery mode, which should contain `/`, `/sbin`, `/proc` etc. where the problem lies (can't find init).

Based on the segfaults you get, it looks like the root ilesystem on `/dev/sda2` may be corrupted. Please run `sudo fsck` on it; you may have to attach an Ubuntu LiveCD ISO to your KVM and boot from that to be able to do so.

A screenshot of the full text preceding the segmentation fault on boot up (see cutoff portion in first screenshot) might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured it out and posted my response below. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @skaz: please consider upvoting then answer and accepting either it or your own so that the question is "closed". Thanks! :)

Comment: Will do - need to wait two days first :(

Comment: Sorry, I forget that -- haven't really asked many questions on AU :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my disk was corrupted. The root disk in the Proxmox environment looks like it is: `/dev/WEBAPPS-LOCAL/root`.

When I ran the Live CD I could not mount this target as I got a seg fault. I couldn't run `fsck` after I tried this: it said I couldn't `fsck` something that was mounted. It must have been in some intermittent state.

I reran the LiveCD again, went into Recovery mode and this time attempted to run no disks as root. Then in the shell I ran `fsck` against `/dev/WEBAPPS-LOCAL/root` and it made some fixes. Then I was able to boot into the server correctly.